# SWFAddress CHANGE Event, dispatch Object

Tags: actionscript-3, swfaddress

Is there a way to dispatch a SWFAdresss CHANGE Event but also pass parameters (an Object) along with it?

I see something like that in the documentation but I can't find an example online...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the SWFAddressEvent class like so:

```
 private var _customObject:Object;

public function SWFAddressEvent(type:String, customObject:Object, bubbles:Boolean = false,  cancelable:Boolean = false) {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

        _customObject = customObject;
    }
```

and then when you dispatch the CHANGE event, add the object to the Event:

```
dispatchEvent(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, customObject);
```

To make the Object publically available:

```
public function get publicCustomObject():Object
{
    return _customObject;
}
```

Comment: That sounds good...does the _customObject have to be public, then?

Comment: _customObject is the private variable we've assigned to the variable passed with the event. If you want the Object to be viewable by other Classes then, for good OOP, I would create a seperate public variable and add a setter, setting the new public variable with _customObject.